# Ruby, How can i access local variables outside the do - end loop

Tags: ruby

I have a loop where i execute a series of command on a remote machine:

```
   ssh.exec('cd /vmfs/volumes/4c6d95d2-b1923d5d-4dd7-f4ce46baaadc/ghettoVCB;  ./ghettoVCB.sh -f vms_to_backup -d dryrun') do|ch, stream, data|
                                    if #{stream} =~ /vmupgrade/
                                    puts value_hosts + " is " + data
                                    puts #{stream}
                                    puts data
                                    end
                            end
```

i want to access #{stream} and data outside the do-end loop

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks,

Hi Jörg,

I implemented your suggestions, but now i am getting error:

```
WrapperghettoVCB.rb:49: odd number list for Hash
      communicator = {ch: ch, stream: stream, data: data}
                         ^
WrapperghettoVCB.rb:49: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
      communicator = {ch: ch, stream: stream, data: data}
                         ^
WrapperghettoVCB.rb:49: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
      communicator = {ch: ch, stream: stream, data: data}
                                     ^
WrapperghettoVCB.rb:49: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
      communicator = {ch: ch, stream: stream, data: data}
                                                   ^
WrapperghettoVCB.rb:76: syntax error, unexpected kELSE, expecting kEND
WrapperghettoVCB.rb:80: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
```

Comment: Sorry, that is the new Ruby 1.9 `Hash` literal syntax for `Hash`es with `Symbol` keys. Just replace all the `foo: bar` with `:foo => bar`. I.e.: `communicator = {:ch => ch, :stream => stream, :data => data}`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't. Local variables are local to their scope. That's why they are called *local variables*.

You could, however, use a variable from an outer scope:

```
communicator = nil

ssh.exec('...') do |ch, stream, data|
  break unless stream =~ /vmupgrade/
  puts "#{value_hosts} is #{data}", stream, data
  communicator = {ch: ch, stream: stream, data: data}
end

puts communicator
```

BTW: there were several bugs in your code, that would have prevented it from working *anyway* regardless of your problem with variable scoping, because you used wrong syntax for dereferencing local variables: the syntax for dereferencing a variable is simply the name of the variable, e.g. `foo`, and not `#{foo}` (that's simply a syntax error).

Also, there are some other improvements:

- *formatting*: the standard for indentation in Ruby is 2 spaces, not 26
- *formatting*: the standard for indentation in Ruby is 2 spaces, not 0
- *formatting*: usually, the block arguments are separated from the `do` keyword with a space
- *guard clause*: if you wrap the *entire* body of a block or method in a conditional, you can just replace that with a guard a the beginning of the block that skips the whole block if the condition is true
- *string interpolation*: adding strings together with `+` is unusual in Ruby; *if* you need to concatenate strings, you usually do it with `<<`, but more often than not, string interpolation is preferred
- *multiple arguments to `puts`*: if you pass multiple arguments to `puts`, it will print all of them on a separate line, you don't need to call it multiple times

Answer (score 5):

```
c, s, d = [nil] * 3
str = '...'
ssh.exec str do |ch, stream, data|
  c, s, d = ch, stream, data
  if #{stream} =~ /vmupgrade/
    puts value_hosts + " is " + data
    puts #{stream}
    puts data
  end
end
```

Someone may suggest that you just reference outer scope variables as the block parameters, but the scoping of block parameter names has changed in Ruby recently and I would suggest playing it safe and just doing it this way.

I don't understand what's going on in the snippet but the general design pattern is often used to yield handles to OS objects and things that are automatically shut down / closed / etc after the block is done, so retaining the Ruby object wrapper may not be useful.

Comment: BTW: I had to puzzle a bit about that first line. If you *really* want to get nifty, I think `c, s, d = []` is less obtuse, but I would prefer `c = s = d = nil`.